# I have a Blutooth Keyboard connected with my Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro, and the Keyboard works, but I dont want the on screen keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I have a Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro, and recently bought a blutooth keyboard for it. They keyboard works, but whenever i click on the area that i want to type something, the on screen keyboard shows up, and i cant use the blutooth one. How do i disable the screen keyboard and only use the blutooth one. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can install and select different keyboard apps from Play Store. Some of them only have a few or even no key(s). Therefore this should be the way to go.

An alternative would be deinstall all keyboard apps, however this is dangerous as there may be situations where the Bluetooth keyboard does not work and you have to enter a password to unlock the device but without keyboard app this won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Open Settings, search for `Show virtual keyboard`. Disable it.